# Adding image from folder to dropdown list

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, office-interop

I want to add images from folder and list it in dropdown . Like my application has folder name flags containing all the flags images and their country name. how do I add them to dropdown .

Comment: Try describing what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `System.IO.Directory.GetFiles` and `System.IO.Path.GetFileName`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getfiles(v=vs.110).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx

Something like (haven't tried it)

```
// Process the list of files found in the directory. 
string [] files = Directory.GetFiles(yourDirectory);
foreach(string file in files) {
    string language = Path.GetFileName(file);
    ddlFlags.Items.Add(new ListItem(language, file));
}
```

Next time, improve your question by describing what you have tried so far, then it would be easier to help you.

Comment: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonDropDownItem' I get this error

Comment: List<string> dirList = new List<string>();
           /// DirectoryInfo[] dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\ANITA\NepaAddintool V1.1\NepaAddintool\Flag").GetDirectories("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);


            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\ANITA\NepaAddintool V1.1\NepaAddintool\Flag\allflags");
            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                string language = Path.GetFileName(file);
                Countryflag.Items.Add(language);
                
               
            }

Answer (score 0):

You should include the `System.IO` namespace and add an `ImageList` to your form. Set its `ImageSize` to a nice size for you images.

Then use the code below to do the rest! It loads all files in a folder into both an `ImageList` and into the `Items` of a `ComboBox`. Note that it loads not the filenames but `FileInfo` objects, so that it can easily display the names without the path. Also note that to display images in a CombBox it has to be `owner-drawn`, which, as you can see it pretty straight-forward..

Here is the code to use & study:

```
  using System.IO;
  //..

  // load whereever you like
  // e.g. in the From.Load event or after InitializeComponent();

  var images = Directory.GetFiles(yourImageFolder, "*.jpg");
  foreach (string file in images)
  {
      imageList1.Images.Add(file, new Bitmap(file));
      comboBox1.Items.Add(new FileInfo(file));
  }
  comboBox1.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
  comboBox1.DrawItem += comboBox1_DrawItem;
  comboBox1.ItemHeight = imageList1.ImageSize.Height;


  void comboBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
  {
     FileInfo FI = (FileInfo)comboBox1.Items[e.Index];
     e.Graphics.DrawImage(imageList1.Images[FI.FullName], e.Bounds.Location);
     e.Graphics.DrawString(FI.Name, Font, Brushes.Black,
            e.Bounds.Left + imageList1.ImageSize.Height + 3, e.Bounds.Top + 4);
  }
```